# How do I access useState inside middleware in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3 with useState to store if a user is logged in or not. Then in the middleware I want to prevent navigation if the user isn't logged in.

composables/states.ts

```
export const useAuth = () => useState<boolean>('authenticated', () => false)
```

middleware/auth.ts

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

// Doesn't work
const {authenticated} = useState('authenticated');

// Doesn't work
const {authenticated} = useAuth();

if (!authenticated) {
    return abortNavigation();
}
})
```

What's the correct way to do this? I couldn't find anything on using useState in middleware or plugins in the docs.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" - what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: The first one authenticated is always false, the second one authenticated is always true. Regardless of what value it has in states.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the few lines that will help you to run the default Nuxt state in your application

**Initialize state**

```js
useState("authenticated", () => false);
```

**Get the state value**

```js
const isAuthenticated = useState("authenticated");
console.log(isAuthenticated.value)
```

**Update the state value**

```js
const isAuthenticated = useState("authenticated");
isAuthenticated.value = true;
```

Now authenticated state value will be changed to `true` and everywhere you will able to receive this value using `const isAuthenticated = useState("authenticated");`